# MariaDB Columnstore not starting when innodb uncommented in my.cnf

Tags: mariadb, innodb, columnstore

I have installed mariadb-columnstore-1.2.2-1-centos7.x86_64 on Centos 7, Single-Server install, internal storage configuration.  There are no errors encountered when running the postConfigure script and the columnstore database starts up just fine.

However, when I uncomment the innodb parameters in /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/my.cnf and restart the database via "stopSystem" and "startSystem" in mcsadmin, the server will not start, seems to be failing when trying to start mysqld.  Re-commenting out the innodb parameters in my.cnf and then starting the server works fine.  Below are the errors I am seeing from the mcsadmin console as well as the error logs. Has anyone else experienced anything similar? Any advice/insight is greatly appreciated!

```
* from the default my.cnf, the innodb parameters in question, uncommented that break the server startup:

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_data_home_dir = /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/lib/mysql/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/lib/mysql/
innodb_log_arch_dir = /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/lib/mysql/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 100M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

* from mcsadmin:

   System being started, please wait...

TIMEOUT: ProcMon not responding to getSystemStatus
**** startSystem Failed : check log files
mcsadmin>

and

[root@db-01 columnstore]# mcsadmin getsystemi
getsysteminfo   Sun Mar 17 23:01:07 2019

System columnstore-1

System and Module statuses

Component     Status                       Last Status Change
------------  --------------------------   ------------------------
System        FAILED                       Sun Mar 17 22:57:07 2019

Module pm1    FAILED                       Sun Mar 17 22:57:05 2019


MariaDB ColumnStore Process statuses

Process             Module    Status            Last Status Change        Process ID
------------------  ------    ---------------   ------------------------  ----------
ProcessMonitor      pm1       ACTIVE            Sun Mar 17 22:54:45 2019       24676
ProcessManager      pm1       ACTIVE            Sun Mar 17 22:54:51 2019       24827
DBRMControllerNode  pm1       MAN_OFFLINE       Sun Mar 17 22:56:46 2019
ServerMonitor       pm1       MAN_OFFLINE       Sun Mar 17 22:56:46 2019
DBRMWorkerNode      pm1       MAN_OFFLINE       Sun Mar 17 22:56:46 2019
DecomSvr            pm1       MAN_OFFLINE       Sun Mar 17 22:56:46 2019
PrimProc            pm1       MAN_OFFLINE       Sun Mar 17 22:56:46 2019
ExeMgr              pm1       MAN_OFFLINE       Sun Mar 17 22:56:46 2019
WriteEngineServer   pm1       MAN_OFFLINE       Sun Mar 17 22:56:46 2019
DDLProc             pm1       MAN_OFFLINE       Sun Mar 17 22:56:46 2019
DMLProc             pm1       MAN_OFFLINE       Sun Mar 17 22:56:46 2019
mysqld              pm1       FAILED            Sun Mar 17 22:57:05 2019

* from the /var/log/mariadb/columnstore/err.log:

Mar 17 22:28:46 db-01 controllernode[2705]: 46.605286 |0|0|0| E 29 CAL0000: DBRM: error: SessionManager::setSystemState() failed (network)
Mar 17 22:28:46 db-01 controllernode[2705]: 46.605690 |0|0|0| E 29 CAL0000: DBRM: error: SessionManager::setSystemState() failed (network)
Mar 17 22:32:43 db-01 oamcpp[15672]: 43.491498 |0|0|0| E 08 CAL0000: ***mysql.pid FILE SIZE EQUALS ZERO
Mar 17 22:32:43 db-01 ProcessMonitor[15672]: 43.491601 |0|0|0| C 18 CAL0000: STARTALL: MySQL failed to start, start-module failure
Mar 17 22:32:45 db-01 ProcessManager[15811]: 45.405253 |0|0|0| C 17 CAL0000: startMgrProcessThread Exit with a failure, error returned from startSystemThread


* from /var/log/mariadb/columnstore/warning.log

Mar 17 22:32:17 db-01 ProcessMonitor[15672]: 17.041254 |0|0|0| I 18 CAL0000:
Mar 17 22:32:17 db-01 ProcessMonitor[15672]: 17.041324 |0|0|0| I 18 CAL0000: **********Process Monitor Started**********
Mar 17 22:32:33 db-01 ProcessMonitor[15672]: 33.998324 |0|0|0| I 18 CAL0000:
Mar 17 22:32:35 db-01 ProcessManager[15811]: 35.019065 |0|0|0| I 17 CAL0000:
Mar 17 22:32:35 db-01 ProcessManager[15811]: 35.019141 |0|0|0| I 17 CAL0000: **********Process Manager Started**********
Mar 17 22:32:35 db-01 ProcessManager[15811]: 35.021371 |0|0|0| I 17 CAL0000: Running Active
Mar 17 22:32:40 db-01 ProcessMonitor[15672]: 40.405513 |0|0|0| I 18 CAL0000: MSG RECEIVED: Start All process request...
Mar 17 22:32:43 db-01 oamcpp[15672]: 43.491498 |0|0|0| E 08 CAL0000: ***mysql.pid FILE SIZE EQUALS ZERO
Mar 17 22:32:43 db-01 ProcessMonitor[15672]: 43.491601 |0|0|0| C 18 CAL0000: STARTALL: MySQL failed to start, start-module failure
Mar 17 22:32:43 db-01 ProcessMonitor[15672]: 43.492527 |0|0|0| I 18 CAL0000: STARTALL: ACK back to ProcMgr, return status = 1
Mar 17 22:32:45 db-01 ProcessManager[15811]: 45.405253 |0|0|0| C 17 CAL0000: startMgrProcessThread Exit with a failure, error returned from startSystemThread

* from /var/log/messages:

Mar 17 22:32:17 db-01 ProcessMonitor[15672]: 17.041254 |0|0|0| I 18 CAL0000:
Mar 17 22:32:17 db-01 ProcessMonitor[15672]: 17.041324 |0|0|0| I 18 CAL0000: **********Process Monitor Started**********
Mar 17 22:32:33 db-01 ProcessMonitor[15672]: 33.998324 |0|0|0| I 18 CAL0000:
Mar 17 22:32:35 db-01 ProcessManager[15811]: 35.019065 |0|0|0| I 17 CAL0000:
Mar 17 22:32:35 db-01 ProcessManager[15811]: 35.019141 |0|0|0| I 17 CAL0000: **********Process Manager Started**********
Mar 17 22:32:35 db-01 ProcessManager[15811]: 35.021371 |0|0|0| I 17 CAL0000: Running Active
Mar 17 22:32:40 db-01 ProcessMonitor[15672]: 40.405513 |0|0|0| I 18 CAL0000: MSG RECEIVED: Start All process request...
Mar 17 22:32:43 db-01 oamcpp[15672]: 43.491498 |0|0|0| E 08 CAL0000: ***mysql.pid FILE SIZE EQUALS ZERO
Mar 17 22:32:43 db-01 ProcessMonitor[15672]: 43.491601 |0|0|0| C 18 CAL0000: STARTALL: MySQL failed to start, start-module failure
Mar 17 22:32:43 db-01 ProcessMonitor[15672]: 43.492527 |0|0|0| I 18 CAL0000: STARTALL: ACK back to ProcMgr, return status = 1
Mar 17 22:32:45 db-01 ProcessManager[15811]: 45.405253 |0|0|0| C 17 CAL0000: startMgrProcessThread Exit with a failure, error returned from startSystemThread
```

Answer (score 0):

There was one log that I forgot to check:

/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/db/db-01.err

which had this error:

2019-03-18 12:30:13 139826114562176 [ERROR] /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql//bin/mysqld: unknown variable 'innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M'

The innodb_additional_mem_pool_size parameter is deprecated.

Commenting out that parameter fixes the problem.